# convert date column into week number, date, month, year

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a date column `Time` in the database which i want to convert into 4 new columns

1. Week
2. day
3. month
4. year

I am using something like this on my `test` database

```
SELECT DATEPART(wk,`Time`), DATEPART(dd,`Time`),DATEPART(mm,`Time`),DATEPART(wk,`yyyy`), FROM `Test` WHERE 1
```

What is wrong in it?

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag, because it doesn't have `DATEPART()`.

Comment: The ` wrapping the indetifiers are MySql, but the `DATEPART` function is Sql server. If it is Sql Server, just remove the ` from the identifiers.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `WHERE 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sql server, you don't wrap your identifiers with `.

However, since `Time` is a data type in sql server, I've wrapped it with `[]`:
Try this query instead:

```
SELECT DATEPART(Week,[Time]) As [Week],
       DATEPART(Day,[Time]) As [Day],
       DATEPART(Month,[Time]) As [Month],
       DATEPART(Year,[Time]) As [Year] 
FROM Test
```

Also, there was an extra comma after the last element in the select clause,
and the Where clause was meaningless, so I've removed it.

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference between doing it like DATEPART and day(time)?

Comment: The only difference is that `datepart` can return different parts of the date, while `day` returns only the day part. `Day(Time)` will return the same thing as `Datepart(Day, Time)`.

Answer (score 0):

**You have wrong syntax to fetch year**  and also extra (,) before From clause

Try as below:

```
SELECT DATEPART(wk,GETDATE()), DATEPART(dd,GETDATE()),DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()),DATEPART(yy,GETDATE())

SELECT DATEPART(week,GETDATE()), DATEPART(day,GETDATE()),DATEPART(month,GETDATE()),DATEPART(year,GETDATE())

SELECT DATEPART(wk,[Time]), DATEPART(dd,[Time]),DATEPART(mm,[Time]),DATEPART(yy,[Time]) From TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select datepart(week,GETDATE()) as [week]
        , datepart(DAY,GETDATE()) as [DAY]
        , datepart(month,GETDATE()) as [month]
         ,datepart(year,GETDATE()) as [year]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also simplify it by using `YEAR`,`MONTH`,`DAY` like this:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(GETDATE()),
    MONTH(GETDATE()),
    DAY(GETDATE()),
    DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE())
```